# How to find docker container by ip?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I got an container ip but do not know which it is, which should be one of dozens containers.
So, what the fastest way to find it out?

Thanks all.

Comment: `kubectl get po --all-namespaces -o wide`

Comment: After colleague's advice，this is works too：“docker ps | awk '{if(NR>2){print $1}}' | xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo "****ip⤴️，id⤵️*****"; echo {}; docker exec {} hostname -i' | grep -A 4 172.20.1.236”

Comment: Why do you have a container IP at all?  What are you actually trying to find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have tagged your question with Kubernetes, so I am assuming you are using that.

Here is how to get container(s) by IP address in k8s:

```
kubectl get pod -ojsonpath='{range .items[*]}{@.metadata.name}{" "}{@.status.podIP}{"\n"}' | grep 127.0.0.1 # <==== Your IP
```

Comment: It works, thanks. I am curious why the command of docker inspect not works like this:   "echo $(docker ps -a -q) | xargs docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }} {{.Id}}' | grep 172.20.1.236"

Comment: @Simon From which machine are you trying to run this? A k8s master or node?

Answer (score 4):

try this :

```
echo $(docker ps -a -q) | xargs docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}  {{.Id}}' | grep MY_IP
```

result :

```
MY_IP  fe82613520e138039924f979899bc46a40312687361a98b9a670273a0340f48c
```

Comment: Not work with this command: echo $(docker ps -a -q) | xargs docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }} {{.Id}}' | grep 172.20.1.236

Answer (score 0):

```
docker inspect  --format={{.Id}}-{{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}} $(docker ps -aq)|grep $IP
```

Comment: docker inspect  --format={{.Id}}-{{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}} $(docker ps -aq)|grep 172.17.0.5
    28f4b232db1ccc84bccac16e7e328c56a033180a9aa5a291a54282dabde9010c-172.17.0.5

Comment: echo $(docker ps -a -q) | xargs docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}  {{.Id}}' | grep 172.20.1.236